# Authors who think war and violence are part of the American culture and economy

Tags: reference-request, political-philosophy, sociology, philosophy-of-war

The United States Military budget exceeds the next 9 countries on the list combined [ref. here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_military_expenditures). A great deal of Hollywood movies portrait the glory of war and present violence as something entertaining and even "funny". In the USA over 2,5% of the population has been to prison [ref. here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incarceration_in_the_United_States) and [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_incarceration_rate#Prison_and_jail_population) which make them number one in the western world. This country has also the highest homicide rate in the developing world only exceeded by Canada [ref. here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_intentional_homicide_rate) and it's the country with most guns per person in the world [ref. here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimated_number_of_civilian_guns_per_capita_by_country)
  Even some mainstream media acknowledges that the USA government started false flags operations such us the Gulf of Tonkin to go to war [ref. here](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2014/aug/02/vietnam-presidents-lie-to-wage-war-iraq) and it's even accepted that there are Central Intelligence agents in the mainstream media as in the disclosed [Operation Mockingbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Mockingbird). Also there is a persistent-through-the-decades army culture in which marines are portrait as heroes and brave role models to society who fight for freedom and obey the "call of duty" no questions asked.

Are there any intellectuals preferably from outside the USA that realise that violence and war are part of the USA culture and economy and if there is a political interest in keeping it that way?

[image: war coffins]

> “Military men are just dumb, stupid animals to be used as pawns in
>   foreign policy.”  Henry Kissinger

Comment: Possible candidates: Culture wars: The struggle to control the family, art, education, law, and politics in America by
James Davison Hunter,
Basic Books, 1992. Simon, J. (2007). Governing through crime: How the war on crime transformed American democracy and created a culture of fear. Oxford University Press.

Comment: Yes. Me. And most others I would think. I can barely believe what goes on in the name of 'freedom' and 'democracy'. I'm not sure about relevant authors. What you describe is all so obvious it doesn't seem worth writing about, .

Comment: Your question seems too general, and the fundamental answer vapid - the USA is the worlds biggest arms dealer and around 10% of GDP is associated with military spending. Violence & war are part of being human. What do prison figures have to with it? Total imprisoned is nearly 2.5% also, nb https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_incarceration_rate#Prison_and_jail_population

Comment: Chomsky for one. Many others. Hard to miss the warmongering of the US government. That's the funny thing. We're told that there's a big "divide" in this country. But there is a centrist consensus for endless semi-covert wars that suck up trillions and nobody bats an eye. Conservatives and liberals agree: When it comes to foreign policy, it's bombs away.

Comment: What is so-wrong about this question that deserves to be closed by so many "philosophers" ?

Comment: @PbxMan 'Tell me people who criticise the USA' is not philosophy.

Comment: @CriglCragl I think social-critique is part of philosophy, the problem is people tend to like criticising others but not others criticising you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gabor Mate](https://www.russellbrand.com/podcast/053-dr-gabor-mate-damaged-leaders-rule-addicted-world/), doctor, author, and addiction specialist, argues that we have a hierarchy which puts traumatised people at the top, who see the world as intrinsically violent and dangerous.

Kate Pickett & Richard Wilkinson, economists and authors of [The Inner Level](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/40163368-the-inner-level), correlate all kinds of social harms including increased need for police, security guards, and prisons, with inequality. There is economic dynamism to inequality also, it can be argued. But we may also be [drifting into neo-feudalism](https://www.economist.com/open-future/2018/06/29/bullshit-jobs-and-the-yoke-of-managerial-feudalism) if we don't consciously determine alternatives.

Kurt Anderson author of Fantasyland: How America Went Haywire, A 500-Year History locates what is distinctive about the USA is [a 'unique history of American religious entrepreneurship'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FDpjKdlIxA).

Anyone who knows [Chomsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_positions_of_Noam_Chomsky#Criticism_of_United_States_government) and [Zizek](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/07393140903322554) knows they argue against US militarism and ideology.

You seem to be asking about the whole of political philosophy applied to the USA, and to be doing so in a way that indicates you have already made up your mind. There are better questions, and answers to seek across many disciplines.

Comment: Gabor Mate seems to have a point.